# Angular ng-click event not firing from controller binding in Directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I have created a simple directive to load a template. Within the template is a binding to a function in the controller that I wanted fired on `ng-click`.

The directive:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('someDirective', someDirective);

function someDirective() {
    var directive = {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/some-directive/some-directive.html',
        controller: 'MyCoolController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        restrict: 'A',
    };

    return directive;
}
```

The controller:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MyCoolController', MyCoolController);

function MyCoolController() {
    var vm = this;

    function clickMe() {
        alert('clicked!');
    }

    cm.clickMe = clickMe;

}
```

The template:

```
<div my-cool-directive>
    <a href="#" ng-click="vm.clickMe()">Click me</a>
</div>
```

My issue is that the `ng-click` event is not firing when the `a` is clicked.

Comment: Was wondering about this myself and ended up making a simple plunkr to demonstrate http://plnkr.co/edit/qQcUPragFYcKIwe3ZLeZ?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

The issue was my lack of understanding how a directive inherits scope. Adding `scope: true` to the directive map corrects the scope for my use case.

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('someDirective', someDirective);

function someDirective() {
    var directive = {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/some-directive/some-directive.html',
        controller: 'MyCoolController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        scope: true, // <-------- Gotcha!
        restrict: 'A',
    };

    return directive;
}
```

There are 3 different types of scopes for directives:

1. Shared scope
2. Inherited scope
3. Isolated scope

For further information see this post: [Understanding scopes in AngularJS custom Directives](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/06/11/understanding-scopes-in-angularjs-custom-directives.aspx)